# Woocommerce: Display Product Variation Description on order page

Tags: php, email, woocommerce, orders, product-variations

I am trying to display the **product variation description** in the order detail page and in the order email. Following this example [Woocommerce: Display Product Variation Description on Cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045038/woocommerce-display-product-variation-description-on-cart-page) it worked perfectly for the cart and also for the checkout. But it seems i can't find the right way of calling it for the order page.

This

```
$item = $cart_item['data'];
if(!empty($item) && $item->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
    echo '<dl><dd>' . $item->get_variation_description() }
```

is not working, as it calls for the cart item data ..
And the get_post_meta as suggested here [WooCommerce displaying variable description after variable price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020948/woocommerce-displaying-variable-description-after-variable-price/41026350#41026350) is not working either.

```
$_variable_description = get_post_meta( $variation->id , '_variation_description', true );
```

I tried to place it in either the **order-details-item.php** and the **class-wc-order-item-meta.php**, and of course the **email-order-details.php**

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution that worked [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/variation-description-in-new-order-email/)  now showing the variation description on the order page and the order email.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_title_as_link', 10, 2 );
function display_product_title_as_link( $item_name, $item ) {

    $_product = get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );

    $link = get_permalink( $_product->id );

    $_var_description ='';

    if ( $item['variation_id'] ) {
        $_var_description = $_product->get_variation_description();
    }

    return '<a href="'. $link .'"  rel="nofollow">'. $item_name .'</a><br>'. $_var_description ;
}
```

It puts the variations description right below the title, but that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Almost 5 years later and this still works and was exactly what I needed for a bakery site I'm building.

I used this combo (in case anyone else comes along):

```
function display_product_title_as_link( $item_name, $item ) {

    $_product = get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );

    $link = get_permalink( $_product->id );

    $_var_description ='';

    if ( $item['variation_id'] ) {
        $_var_description = $_product->get_variation_description();
    }

    return '<a href="'. $link .'"  rel="nofollow">'. $item_name .'</a><br>'. $_var_description ;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes','__return_false' );
```

I really appreciate being able to find answers here.

Comment: where did you placed the code? In the functions.php or in the order-details email? It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_description', 10, 2 );
    function display_product_description( $item_name, $item ) {

        $_product = get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );


        $_var_description ='';

        if ( $item['variation_id'] ) {
            $_var_description = $_product->get_variation_description();
        }

        return $_var_description ;
    }
```

Try this in you theme's functions.php

Comment: It works, as it now displays the variation description on the order page and email. BUT now it displays the description instead the name of the product ..

Answer (score 0):

**Finally found a solution that worked**
Problem solved, add this to child theme function.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
```